# SQLSTATE[42S02] Laravel error

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, artisan

После изменения файла web.php а точнее замена строчки

```
Route::get('project', function () {
    //$project = DB::table('project')->get(); --- Вот эту строчку
    $project = App\Project::all(); --- Заменил на эту
    return view('project.main', compact('project'));
});
```

Стала выползать ошибка

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.projects' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `projects`) .

Все бы хорошо, но я не создавал таблицы projects , у меня таблица project . И он не как не хочет её убирать . При этом файл Project.php (это файл модели) полностью пустой . 
Но если я верну результат как было до этого, то все прекрасно работает !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По дефолту модель Laravel использует таблицу исходя из имени класса во множественном числе. Если у вас модель **Project** обращаться она будет к таблице **projects**.
Вы можете задать таблицу вручную, используя свойство в классе модели.

`protected $table = 'project';`

Рекомендую ознакомиться с [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

Answer (score 0):

Как такого решения не нашел. 
Но после того как перезаписал все данные миграции, появилась таблица project , и решил использовать её до конца.